# Command for Creating a new MySQL database using CMD or TERMINAL

Tags: mysql, cmd, terminal

I need to create MySQL database from terminal or CMD. I have tried this command.

```
CREATE DATABASE something
```

Comment: Please add commands/code as text not as image

Comment: @Jens Thank you so much for pointing out my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
<Path to mysql>mysql -u root -p -e "create database something"
```

After you press enter you should get propted to enter your password

Comment: I entered command mysql -u root -p -e "something"
and I am getting an error
"ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'something' at line 1"

Comment: @SAIFAHMEDANIK you forgot `create database` please read the answer carefuly

Answer (score 0):

You need to install mysql server from [here](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/install-mysql/) in windows machine
 and then fire following commands,

```
create database database_name;
use database_name;
```

and create your tables.

Answer (score 0):

Send the following command:

```
mysql.exe -u<user> -p<password>
```

You'll be prompted for a password:

[image: Password requested output]

Then create your database using:

```
create database <dbname>
```

[image: Database creation output]